# No in-app purchase for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've been googling, and come to this understanding that in-app purchase is not possible for windows phone 7.

If I understand It correct you could add IAP to a WP7 project and if the application runs on a WP8 device it would be available, correct?

A secondary method is to use a third party that has implemented a browser thingy to make purchases from within your app?

But as it is there is no IAP for WP7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. There is no in-app purchase for WP7.

You are alowed to implement you own or use any third-part IAP.

For WP8 client you can use build-in IAP service.

Comment: Do you know about any third party IAPs?

Comment: I just ran into this problem. I ended up making separate WP7 and WP8 apps. WP8 - free w/IAP, WP7 app paid w/free trial. Keep in mind that WP7 is gradually going to fade away as people move to WP8.